# How can i scrape collection of images using simple dom

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape the images of flipkart product but i get the placeholder images but not the actual product image. also i display the alt tag from image tag. alt attribute showing correct values of alt tag but not getting the correct source of image

'''

```
      require 'simple_html_dom.php';

      $prduct_name = $_GET['prod'];

      $url = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q='".$prduct_name."'&sid=tyy%2C4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_QueryStore_HistoryAutoSuggest_0_0&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_HistoryAutoSuggest_0_0&as-pos=0&as-type=HISTORY";

      $html = file_get_html($url);


      foreach ($html->find('div._3O0U0u') as $div) {
        $title = $div->find('div._3wU53n', 0)->plaintext;
        $price = $div->find('div._2rQ-NK', 0)->plaintext;
        $imgscr = $div->find('img._1Nyybr', 0)->src;
        $alt = $div->find('img._1Nyybr', 0)->alt;
        $link = $div->find('a._31qSD5', 0)->href;

        ?>   
      <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card card-lift--hover shadow border-0">
              <div class="card-body py-5">
                <img src="<?php echo $imgscr; ?>" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" height="200" width="100">
                  <br> 
                <h6 class="text-primary text-uppercase text-center"><?php echo $title; ?></h6>
              <div>
                  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Price : <?php echo $price; ?> </span>
              </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <a href="compare.php?prod=<?php echo $title; ?>&url=https://www.flipkart.com<?php echo $link;?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mt-4">Compare</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <a href="https://www.flipkart.com<?php echo $link;?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mt-4">View Product</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
       </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

'''

I want the actual value src attribute

```
<img class="_1Nyybr Yun65Y _30XEf0" alt="Redmi Note 7 (Onyx Black, 64 GB)" src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/832/832/jskofww0/mobile/e/k/z/mi-redmi-note-7-na-original-imafe48yggp2za54.jpeg?q=70">
```

like the link of image but its giving me

```
<img class="_1Nyybr Yun65Y _30XEf0" alt="Redmi Note 7 (Onyx Black, 64 GB)" src="//img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/placeholder_9951d0.svg">
```

Comment: Those div classes are dynamic, you can't expect them to be there next time.

Comment: I think they are not dynamic because i am getting the alt attribute value but not getting the src attribute value if they are dynamic then i don't get alt attribute value  of same image